# how to link arrays value via a function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, database, function

i finally solved and link arrays via to function and compare arrays values via strcmp. Thanks for all your help!! Do hope you guys can refer to the answer as listed in my question and post.

Shoutout to everyone that commented and advised accordingly. Appreciate it.

**My solution was to solved it by using 2D Arrays - char instead of string + using strcmp at function to compare value sets to achieve objectives of Lab7.**

Best,

MM

```
// Marcus Moo Lab 7.cpp
// Full Time Student
// No plagarism

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Global Declarations
const float pointLaw[11] = { 5.0,5.0,4.5,4.0,3.5,3.0,2.5,2.0,1.5,1.0,0.0 };
const char gradeLaw[11][3] = { "A+","A","A-","B+","B","B-","C+","C","D+","D","F" };

// Convert Grade to Point
float gradeToPoint(const char grade[]);

int main()
{
    // Header
    cout << "\tWelcome to University Of Wollongong" << endl;
    cout << "Grade Point Consultation System" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Defining moments
    char grade[3];
    float outcome;
    char intent;
    int count;

    // Purpose of consultation system
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your grade: ";
        cin >> grade;
        outcome = gradeToPoint(grade);
        if (outcome == -1) {
            cout << "Invalid Grade" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Your grade point is " << outcome << endl;
        }
        cout << "Continue?: ";
        cin >> intent;
        cout << endl;

    } while ((intent == 'y') || (intent == 'Y'));

    // The end
    cout << "All the best" << endl;
}

float gradeToPoint(const char grade[])
{
    int count;
    float points = -1;
    for (count = 0; count < 12; count++)
    {
        if (strcmp(gradeLaw[count], grade) == 0) {
            points = pointLaw[count];
            cout << gradeLaw[count] << " = " << grade << endl;
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

Comment: Use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: @NathanOliver wasn't taught std::map in school?

What other methods are there?

Comment: @NathanOliver why did you downvote this question anyway? I tried to ask it in a more general manner already though.

Comment: I did not down vote your question.

Comment: @NathanOliver opps but thanks for ur advice!

Comment: learn to use a map and get extra credit

Comment: @pm100 I understand how to use it already! Do credit me for hardwork haha

Comment: @pm100 do advise, i reedited the code

Comment: @NathanOliver do advise, i reedited the code

Comment: Hi. I reverted the edit. Please don't change the question after accepting an answer. It makes it really hard for future users to understand the answer if the question asks something else.

Comment: @NathanOliver i solved it!

Comment: @pm100 I solved it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier method is to model a record (think of a row in a table), using a structure:

```
struct Name_Grade
{
  std::string grade;
  double      point;
};
```

This will pair a grade with a point value.

Now to declare an array of each:

```
static const grade_table[] =
{
  {"A+", 5.0}, {"A", 5.0}, {"A-", 4.5}, //...
};
size_t rows_in_table =
  sizeof(grade_table) / sizeof(grade_table[0]);
```

Your function becomes:

```
double gradeToPoint(const std::string& grade)
{
  double point = 0.0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_in_table; ++i)
  {
    if (grade == grade_table[i].grade)
    {
      point = grade_table[i].point;
      break;
    }
  }
  return point;
}
```

Using parallel arrays:

```
double grade_to_point(const std::string& grade)
{
  static const std::string grade_texts[]=
     {"A+", "A", "A-",
      "B+", "B", "B-",
      "C+", "C", "C-",
      "D+", "D",
      "F"};
  static const double point[] = 
     {5.0,5.0,4.5,
      3.5,3.0,2.5,
      2.5,2.0,1.5,
      1.0,0.5,
      0.0};
  static const size_t grade_quantity =
      sizeof(point) / sizeof(point[0]);

  double grade_value = 0.0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < grade_quantity; ++i)
  {
    if (grade == grade_texts[i])
    {
      grade_value = point[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return grade_value;
}
```

One issue with parallel arrays is that the arrays can be different sizes, or unsynchronized.  Thus the safer and more robust method is to keep the grade text with the point value (the `struct` method).

Comment: Why unsigned int as the type for a ratio of size of? Otherwise some good stuff here.

Comment: My lecturer specifically want us to do it via the manner in which i depict in the question. I wish I can use the method that you advise though

Comment: @Bathsheba:  `unsigned int` because sizes can't be negative. :-)  Yes, I should use `size_t`.

Comment: @KayzelMoo:  You asked "what other methods are there?" and I supplied one.

Comment: I'll upvote if you do. unsigned int maximum could be as small as 65535.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks Thomas. I understand already, they have to crawl the value from arrays individually.

Comment: note that this doesnt deal with GPA = 4.6 or 2.3 etc

Comment: @pm100 do you mind doing up another solution that can catered to 4.6/2.3 
because it's more general and has scalability

Comment: @KayzelMoo:  I don't understand.  Given a grade text, you can't get a point value of 4.6.  Search the internet for "linear interpolation" or do a reverse lookup and find the best fit.

Comment: @KayzelMoo I was about to delete my comment, since I thought the code was number goes to grade letter, but in fact its grade letter goes to number. Ie the user enteres A and you say 5.0. So my comment makes not sense, as Thomas says. So, what does the user enter a number of a letter?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews hey Thomas! i was taught never to use break in a loop or even "if" function or he will make me take a break next sem.

Comment: You could use array access if you multiply the grade point by 10 and one letter entry for each of the possible grade point values (multiplied by 10).

Comment: @KayzelMoo:  Nothing wrong in industry with a `break` like this.  Use a `bool` variable called "found".  Set to false before the loop and add it to one of the terminating conditions.  Set to true if the grade was found.  You'll continue the loop if `found` is false.

Comment: @KayzelMoo then yr teacher is not very good. (I was going to say worse things). This is a perfect example of where break makes sense, its clear and correct.

Comment: @pm100 point taken again!
I just think that he doesnt want us to have a bad habit of breaking a loop 
e.g. do while, for

thomas, i understand bool found method! cool. but lets say theres >1000 datas - Name must match to where they stay, credit card number etc (practical app solution in industry) - will the method u advised be ideal

Comment: @KayzelMoo:  We use this method all the time in embedded systems.  For large data, the data will not be stored in the executable, but an external source such as a data file or a database.  Different methods for different quantities of data.  Also, data that is frequently accessed will usually be in the executable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews aye capt

Comment: must i use size_t i = 0; i can also just int count = 0; if count <12; count++??
OR
const int x = 12;
const char grade[x]
const double point[x]

Comment: The `int` type is *signed* meaning it can go negative.  The `unsigned int` has a larger range.  However, the `sizeof` operator returns its value in a `size_t` data type.  This data type is carried over to the `for` loop.

Comment: Looks like the only change you made was to make the arrays constant.  The function is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you said you were not taught maps, but for future reference this can be easily solved with one. Just in case you end up wanting to use a map, it can be done cleanly like so:

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, double> grades ( {{"A+",5.0},{"A", 5.0},{"A-", 4.5},
    {"B+", 4.0},{"B", 3.5},{"B-", 3.0},{"C+", 2.5},{"C", 2.0},{"C-", 1.5},
    {"D+", 1.0},{"D", 0.5},{"D-", 0.0},{"F", 0.0}} );
```

And then you can get the grades via `grade["yourLetterGradeHere"]` notation.
Just make sure to `#include <unordered_map>` at the top of your program

Comment: so unordered_map itself is a library function?

Comment: Yes, unordered_map is a library data structure included in C++'s standard template library

Comment: Thanks!! michael appreciate it

Comment: An issue with `std::map` is that it's efficient for only one direction.  Converting from the other direction is painful.

Comment: Why use an *unordered* map vs. `std::map`?

Comment: Either implementation (map or unordered_map) works. unordered_map is just a tiny bit faster than map for the OP's use case - static data set where the data structure will just be used for lookups.